# Is it possible to define a return type with an arbitrary type parameter?

Tags: scala, types

Assume, we have a a class with an type parameter

```
class A[T]
```

And we want to write a method, that returns objects of the type `A` with an arbritrary type parameter, like:

```
def f: A = { ... }
```

The compiler will complain about the missing type parameter for type `A`.

We can not solve this problem by writing `A[Any]`, since e.g. `A[String]` is no subtype of `A[Any]`. But we can reach this subtype relation with a covariant annotation of `+T`.

Is it possible write such a method `f` without using covariant annotation `+T` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use existential types:

```
def f: A[_] = { ... }
```

This is shorthand for:

```
def f: A[T forSome { type T }] = { ... }
```

You can even use upper (or lower) bounds:

```
def f: A[_ <: SomeType] = { ... }
```

You can assign any type `T` to this, however, you may not be able to do anything useful with the result